# Marketing Cloud : Attach and send PDF file from SFTP based on Salesforce CRM data

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

Our existing CRM is Salesforce and we have purchased Marketing Cloud and would like to whether the following usecase is feasible.

We have a unique Id (CusId__c) for our customers (Contact Object) and a set of PDFs named with the same unique Id in our SFTP server.

For example, Customer A with the unique Id (CusId__c) as "1000" will have a PDF named "1000.pdf" in our SFTP and Customer B with the unique Id (CusId__c) as "2000" will have a PDF named "2000.pdf" in our SFTP etc

We would like to know if it is possible to dynamically attach "1000.PDF" to customer A and "2000.pdf" to customer B when we send email from Marketing Cloud

A high level pointers/guidelines/links is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You can only attach files that are stored in Marketing Cloud’s SFTP or in Content Builder, or files that have a HTTP url available.

Take a look at the [AttachFile](https://ampscript.guide/attachfile/) AMPscript function:

> Type of location containing the file to attach.
>
> Valid values include:
>
> ContentBuilder
>
> FTP
>
> HTTP
>
> Portfolio (Classic Content)

That said, unless the SFTP you mentioned belongs to Marketing Cloud, you won’t be able to attach them dynamically.

Take a look at this workaround if needed: [Attach file from external (S)FTP using AMPScript](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/144511/attach-file-from-external-sftp-using-ampscript)

And note, that Email Attachments need to be activated by Salesforce Support first, the AttachFile function won’t work otherwise.